# Multiplicative groups of skew fields

Tags: gr.group-theory, division-rings

Is every group isomorphic to a subgroup of the multiplicative group of some skew field?

Comment: Not every finite group does: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2001-129-11/S0002-9939-01-05961-5/S0002-9939-01-05961-5.pdf (T. Lam, finite groups embeddable in division rings, Proc AMS 2001), referring to Amitsur, 1955

Comment: I don't know whether there's any torsion-free known counterexample. Every bi-orderable group (e.g., torsion-free nilpotent, free group...) indeed embeds (Malcev). Also every torsion-free solvable group.

Answer (score 16):

No. Indeed, every finite abelian subgroup is cyclic. Indeed, passing to the subfield it generates, we boil down to the standard easy fact that in a field every finite abelian subgroup of the multiplicative group is cyclic (a non-abelian finite group contains $C_p^2$ for some $p$, where $C_p$ means a cyclic group of order $p$, and we would get $p^2$ $p$-roots of $1$ in a field).

Comment: Note that if you just want to see not all groups appear, then you don't need general field theory: explicitly, you can consider a group like $C_2^2$ and recall that in a division ring, $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$ has at most two roots.

Comment: The general field theory is not deep, just that $x^p-1$ has at most $p$ roots in every field, for any prime $p$. Indeed at a very elementary level it's a bit more immediate for $p=2$ since $x^2-1$ splits.